# Is it possible to access scores of an iOS game application within other iOS application?

Tags: ios, iphone, game-center, gamekit, leaderboard

I want to access score of user **'A'** that he/she secure in **Game_Application_1** within **Game_Application_2** when user **'B'** playing **Game_Application_2**.

Assuming user **A** given permission to access thier score.

Both Application developed by different developer.

Please let me know it is possible or not and if possible then how?

Thank you.

Comment: Will you be making both games?

Comment: No,I am not making both game. Can it possible if I make both game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This totally depends, if you developing both app then yes. Storing the scores in the keychain can make it accessible to both app.

If you are you are not the developer of both apps then probably no, unless you have access to some kind of API that could tell you the score. Since you can not access data from other app the developers of the other should provide an API to allow you access the score. This can be web based of even using an App URL Scheme.

Comment: Thank you rckoenes,
I am new in gaming app development so I do not have much idea of gaming app.
Could you explain how it is possible if I developing both app or suggest me any link from where I read about it. Does Game center, leadersboard or iOS gaming framework not provide this?

Comment: You should start by reading the [Apple iOS developers documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started). Because your question has become to big to have a simple answer for stack overflow. Just start learn the frameworks before just posting your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If both apps are yours you can easily use iCloud's key-value Store to share information.

See Apple's [Key-Value Data in iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html).
See NSHipster's [iCloud article](http://nshipster.com/icloud/).

Answer (score 0):

In ios application you can't access data from out side the application bundle. If you want any information or data from out side the application bundle then you should use API (web services) which contain those information.